# Problems prompting user for input in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

```
import sys
import turtle
t=turtle.Pen
def what_to_draw():
    print ("What to do you want to see a sketch of that may or may not be colored?")
what_to_draw=sys.stdin.readline()
if what_to_draw=="flower/n":
    t.forward(90)
elif():
    print ("What you typed isn't in the code. Try putting a letter or letters to lowercase or uppercase. If that doesn't work, what you typed has not been set to make something happen")
```

I typed in this code above. It says in the  python shell "flower" isn't defined. Can someone figure this out for me?

Answer (score 2):

Several lines of your code have errors of some sort:

`t=turtle.Pen` should be: `t = turtle.Pen()`

You should avoid functions and variables with the same name

```
def what_to_draw():
    ...
    what_to_draw = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Use rstrip() to deal with "\n" and .lower() to deal with case:

```
if what_to_draw == "flower/n":
```

`elif():` requires a condition of some sort otherwise use `else:`

Let's try a different approach.  Instead of mixing console window input with turtle graphics, let's try to do everything from within turtle using the `textinput()` function that's new with Python 3 turtle:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def what_to_draw():
    title = "Make a sketch."

    while True:
        to_draw = screen.textinput(title, "What do you want to see?")

        if to_draw is None:  # user hit Cancel so quit
            break

        to_draw = to_draw.strip().lower()  # clean up input

        if to_draw == "flower":
            tortoise.forward(90)  # draw a flower here
            break
        elif to_draw == "frog":
            tortoise.backward(90)  # draw a frog here
            break
        else:
            title = to_draw.capitalize() + " isn't in the code."

tortoise = Turtle()

screen = Screen()

what_to_draw()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Winston, I've rearranged my example slightly to make it simpler to add new drawing options.  As far as what the prompts say, that's up to you -- just check that your messages fit in the relatively small text input boxes.

Comment: And is it possible to make the input box bigger?

Comment: I changed to code slightly,  but when I copy and paste the new code, it won't let me add the comment

Answer (score 0):

Your indentations are wrong, so most of the statements are outside the function body of `what_to_draw()`.
You don't actually call the function, so it won't do anything.
Also, don't use the `what_to_draw` as a function name and a variable name.
There shouldn't be `()` after `elif:`
Instead of `print()` and `stdin`, use `input()` . You don't get the `\n` that way as well.

Try this and let me know:

```
import sys
import turtle
t=turtle.Pen()
def what_to_draw():
    draw_this = input("What to do you want to see a sketch of that may or may not be colored?")
    if draw_this == "flower":
        t.forward(90)
    elif:
        print ("What you typed isn't in the code. Try putting a letter or letters to lowercase or uppercase. If that doesn't work, what you typed has not been set to make something happen")

what_to_draw()
```

Comment: That is a different question. If it doesn't work then there is a logic problem in your code now. You should work at it and try to figure out what it is your commands are missing. The reason your code was not functioning at all, as stated in the question is resolved. You should mark this as answered and try to solve it yourself.

Comment: No, study the material again, from a different source if the current one isn't working for you. google it. You will encounter many such slowdowns in programming. The computer does exactly what you tell it do, no more no less.

Comment: I'm not compelling you. Dracula does that. Your question has been answered. Now you are facing a different problem. The question was "why is it giving flower not defined". That has been helped with and a lot more than that.

Comment: Accepting an answer is thanks for people who used their time to help out a stranger. You are telling the turtle to move 90 pixels forward, and it does. It won't draw a flower from that one statement. Also, did you look into turtle.mainloop() as suggested by someone here?

Comment: This comment thread is becoming unwieldy and unhelpful for future readers. Open a new question and post the code that is not working.